# How to overlay images on each other and write text on it in css?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

Here is a design that i am trying to achieve I am using ionic+vue+css for this purpose .
Design is

[image]

The background image and top search bar is already set.This design has different components in the form of images

Top Curve

[image]

Bottom Curve
[image]

Headphone image
[image]

I just want to overlay on eaach other should be able to write some text on it here is my code which i have did till now
its vue js+css code

```
<template>
  <IonPage>

    <ion-content :fullscreen="true" id="start">

      <div id="background">
        <Topbar />
        <img :src="require('@/assets/kurve_top.png')" />

        ARCTICS PRO PRODUCT PAGE

</div>

    </ion-content>

  </IonPage>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonContent, IonPage  } from '@ionic/vue';
import Topbar from '../Resources/Topbar.vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default  {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {IonContent, IonPage, Topbar },
  setup() {

    return {
      router: useRouter(),
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#background {
    padding: 20px;
    background: url("/assets/kurve_top.svg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

This is how it looks like at the moment

[image]

Comment: that's not a good idea to merge all images with CSS. you will have issue with other images. Merge all images using photoshop and use it as background image.